# Get the players name and score

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms

What I want to do is use a Data Table to get data from my `mySQL` to show in a `Listbox` on my form.

How can I get a players name and score to show up in order of highest score?

So far i managed to get a players name or a players score to show up.

```
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

string sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM highscore";

MySqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, myConn);

DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
dAdapter.Dispose();
lstNames.DataSource = dTable;
lstScores.DataSource = dTable;
lstNames.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

I did try to use two separate list boxes out of ease, but realized i wouldn't be able to arrange them in any order.

Below is after the changes Paul

```
                 MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

             string sqlStr = "SELECT Name + ' ' + Score as NameAndScore " + "FROM highscore ORDER BY Score DESC";

             MySqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, myConn);

             DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
             dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
             dAdapter.Dispose();
             lstNames.DisplayMember = "NameAndScore";
             lstNames.DataSource = dTable;
```

Comment: Sounds like what you really want here may be a GridView or a DataGrid rather than a list.

Comment: I did have a play with a DataGrid but i found the list to be the simpler option as i dont need any of the data to be edited, updated or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You could do quite a bit with your SQL:

```
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

string sqlStr = "SELECT CONCAT(Name, ' ', Score) as NameAndScore " +
                "FROM highscore ORDER BY Score DESC";

MySqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, myConn);

DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
dAdapter.Dispose();
lstNames.DisplayMember = "NameAndScore";
lstNames.DataSource = dTable;
```

Comment: i tried just changing the SQL and in the lstbox i got "System.Data.Datarowview" do you think the above would fix that, not sure why it has started to do that, it seemed to be showing results before i changed it

Comment: That's because you're setting the DisplayMember after the fact. You need to change it before you populate the view. Also notice that I changed the output to an aliased field named `NameAndScore`. You have to match that exactly in your DisplayMember property.

Comment: sorry Paul, which of the statements is the fact? I just ran the program with the above suggestions and got this 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[NameAndScore] FROM highscore ORDER BY Score DESC' at line 1' when it tried to do 'dAdapter.Fill(dTable);'

Comment: @CainNeal: Oops. I had SQL Server syntax for the alias. Try wothout the square brackets. I made the change in the code example too.

Comment: all that shows is the scores without names. But it does show them in descending order.

Comment: Please put your code into your question. There is obviously something missing

Comment: Actually, plz check my answer again. Use the CONCAT operator to combine the strings for output...

Comment: im testing it now, takes a while. I posted my code anyway in my question below the origional code i posted

Comment: earlier you said i was getting an error because i was posting the DisplayMember before the fact. Which Statement is the fact?

Comment: There is not a single fact. There are/were several issues. Please use my most recent as a guide.

Comment: @CainNeal: ok. I tried my best to put together a complete snippet from your code and mine. Please see my edit and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that the field that holds the score is 'score', your query could be

string sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM highscore order by score DESC";

Basically You need to order your records in descending order by score. This should  be simple

let me know if you have more issues

Comment: this should be a comment it doesn't help the OP much when you just post a response without any valid working example or link to documented working source